# How to pass in constructor arguments with new

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass in arguments into a constructor but meanwhile making an array of objects like that.  I used the following code to get there:

`PointPtr centroids = new Point[k](5);`

Well, that wasn't a syntax error, but it didn't compile.  I didn't really want to hard-code "5" into a default constructor for Point.  Got any ideas on how I should do this?  Thanks!

BTW, I did `typedef Point *PointPtr` somewhere else already.

Sorry if the title wasn't accurate.  I didn't know how to summarize this.

Comment: Sorry you can't do that with dynamic arrays. Consider using a vector, which lets use `emplace_back` to construct objects.

Comment: Yet another reason to avoid `new` .

Comment: Yeah... for my assignment, I can't use vectors yet.

Comment: You'll have to write `fill(centroids, centroids + k, 5);`

Comment: It is always "yet".. why they aren't taught first?

Comment: That's where schools mess up big time. In my school they don't teach `std::vector` or even `std::string`. That's why I always skip class...

Comment: There must be an insatiable demand in the world for homebrew array, string and list classes that I don't know about.

Comment: `but here's another question` - no, if you have more questions, please ask them separately. One post = one question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry sir but this is a very similar question.

Comment: It is so similar that it doesn't even require asking. Take the time to understand the answers you got for your first question, and then try to apply them to solve your second one.

Comment: Ahh nvm all, I was able to fix the problem.  Thanks to all the people who fixed the problem!

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can create an array of pointers (i.e. `Point**`) and initialize them in 2 steps:

1. create the array:

   `PointPtr* centroids = new PointPtr[k];`
2. Initialize:

   `for (int i=0 ; i<k ; ++i)
       centroids[i]=new Point(5);`

Comment: Yeah no. This isn't Java.

Comment: True that, I can't do that #1 because I don't have a default ctor :|

Comment: I ws thinking about java for a moment. Sorry. Edited with a C++ proposal.

Comment: Hmm.  Very very smart!  Thanks!

Comment: I read your edit. You should apply the exact same technique as before.

Comment: Note that this solution gives a different type to `centroids`; in the original, it is a `Point*` and in your solution it becomes `Point**`. This really should be made more apparent in the answer.

Comment: Although it circumvents the actual problem, the memory layout of this solution is unpredictable.

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest using a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Point> v(k, Point{5});
```

But you can also do it as:

```
Point* centroids = new Point[5]{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f336d8a3fb6c7825)

Comment: I didn't know about that way!

Comment: Does this non-vector solution also work when `Point` is not an aggregate?

Comment: @MicroVirus Yes, if you provide a constructor that takes an `int`.

Comment: @szczurcio This [live demo with constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91d8064610b98a93) doesn't compile.

Comment: @MicroVirus That's interesting, the very same code compiles fine in VS15 (MSVC 14.0). Clang says `candidate constructor not viable` because it `requires single argument 'x', but no arguments were provided` which is odd, but I may be mistaken in my interpretation of the standard. One of the compilers is behaving in a nonstandard way then.

Comment: @MicroVirus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989510/aggregate-initialization-of-an-array-of-objects-with-new-which-compiler-is-rig

Comment: Nice :) Let's see what turns up.

Comment: @101010 [Does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91d8064610b98a93)!

Comment: @John looks like it does [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c0684ec51ca64c0)

Answer (score 5):

> *Note 1: Using the standard library (namely `std::vector` in this case) to handle things is prefereable!*
>
> *Note 2: Personally, I wouldn't go down the array of pointers route because you destroy your memory locality.*

You can use [`std::allocator`](http://%60http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) :

```
// Create allocator object
std::allocator<Point> alloc;
// allocate storage for k Points
Point * p = alloc.allocate(k);
// Construct k Points in p
for (std::size_t i{0}; i<k; ++i)
{
  alloc.construct(p+i, 5);
}
// Do stuff using p
// ...
// Destroy k objects in p
for (std::size_t i{0}; i<k; ++i)
{
  alloc.destroy(p+i);
}
// Dealloacte memory
alloc.deallocate(p, k);
```

or you can handle it manually

```
// allocate
Point * p = static_cast<Point*>(::operator new[](k*sizeof(Point)));
// placement new construction
for (std::size_t i{0}; i<k; ++i)
{
  new((void *)(p+i)) Point{5};
}
// stuff
// destruction
for (std::size_t i{0}; i<k; ++i)
{
  (p+i)->~Point();
}
// deallocation
::operator delete[](static_cast<void*>(p));
```

where I'd wrap the memory handling into functions (if not a class) at least:

```
#include <new>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template<class T, class ... Args>
T * new_n(std::size_t const n, Args&&  ... args)
{
  T * p{ (T*)::operator new[](n*sizeof(T)) };
  for (std::size_t i{ 0 }; i < n; ++i) 
  {
    new((void*)(p + i)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  return p;
}

template<class T>
void remove_n(T * const p, std::size_t const n)
{
  for (std::size_t i{ 0 }; i < n; ++i) (p + i)->~T();
  ::operator delete[]((void*)p);
}
```

and use them

```
auto p = new_n<Point>(k, 5);
// stuff using k Points in p constructed by passing 5 to constructors
remove_n(p, k);
```

Comment: So um, as I stated in another comment, I cannot use the STL for this assignment.  I can use it for another, but I have to submit just pointers for this assignment.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: `std::size_t i{0}` - this is by far the most original way of initializing a loop variable I've seen :P

Comment: `std::size_t i{}` would also suffice, wouldn't it? I know C doesn't allow empty braces but I was under the impression that C++ did.

Comment: @JackThomas You can do what `std::allocator` does by hand but manual memory management is usually not a very good idea.

Comment: this is not correct: in remove_n the array elements need to be destructed in reverse order!

Comment: @AndreasH.: I don't even know where to start when counting things that are wrong with my code in this answer ... but reverse order destruction is not amongst those things. Designing a class in a way that destruction must happen in reverse order with respect to construction is a path into a tight corner, almost nobody would want to be in. `remove_n` just doesn't destroy in reverse order. There is no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use `std::vector`, then an option is to dynamically allocate an array of pointers, then dynamically allocate n objects and assign the resulting memory to the pointers in the array. For example:

```
constexpr auto ARRAYSIZE = 5;

auto x = new PointPtr[ARRAYSIZE];  // should check for memory alloc errors
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; ++i)
{
    x[i] = new Point(5); // pass any arguments you want, remember to check if allocation was successful
}
```

Note that such practices frowned upon because you should really never use `new` unless you have a very good reason to do so (and IMO it's stupid that you're not allowed to do things the proper way and taught good practices from the start); instead use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and smart pointers, they should be able to satisfy all your dynamic memory needs.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base {
   public:
    int p, q;
    base() {}
    base(int a, int b) : p(a), q(b) {
        cout << p << q;
    }
};

int main() {
    int a, b;
    base *ptr = new base[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        cin >> a >> b;
        ptr[i] = base(a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```