# Aggregate initialization of an array of objects with new which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, c++14

Supposedly, I have the following code:

```
class Foo { 
  int i;
public:
  Foo(int const i_) : i(i_) {}
  int geti() const { return i; }
};

int main()
{
  Foo* bar = new Foo[5]{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}};
}
```

GCC compiles and runs it with no problem [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e321f4c2611e538), while CLANG gives a compile error [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87bbb3f8b9a8c229)

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Foo'

So which compiler is right?

Comment: I can also report that MSVC 14.0 has no problems with it either. Note that the extra internal braces can be removed as this doesn't change anything in this case.

Comment: How about trying just `new Foo[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. I haven't used this syntax so I don't even know if this is valid, but I suspect that the simpler a statement is, the more compilers will accept it.

Comment: The [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) page on cppreference says "the elements of the array are aggregate-initialized.", so that seems to imply that `Foo` needs to be an aggregate for this to be legal.

Comment: @MicroVirus in that context, the aggregate is the array

Comment: @M.M The elements are aggregate-initialised, so the elements must be aggregates to be able to be initialised this way. At least, that's what I'd conclude from it.

Comment: The C++14 standard actually says "the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-
initialization."  So I'd consider it sloppy summarizing by cppreference in this case.

Comment: One note aside, there is nothing ambiguous in writing ´Foo(int const i) : i(i) {}´

Comment: This is [Clang bug 22924](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22924) and [CWG issue 2102](http://wg21.link/CWG2102). @MicroVirus If that page says that, it needs to be changed.

Comment: @101010 wow - used to dealing with odd balls! :P

Comment: @T.C. Under **Construction** the [cppreference new page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) says "If initializer is a brace-enclosed list of arguments, the elements of the array are aggregate-initialized.". If that's inaccurate, then it would be nice if it were changed. I, however, am not qualified to make such a change.